# tex4ht: getting accented letters in small capitals through \selectfont

Tags: luatex, tex4ht, html, small-caps

I try to get small capitals in my `html` document, but the `tex4ht` code that I found works only for the command `\textsc`. however, I enter all my change of font through `\rmfamily\mdseries\scshape\selectfont` and so the accented letters are not turned into small capitals.

i compile with make4ht -ul hello.tex

I use an extension of tex4ht by @michal.h21,

https://github.com/michal-h21/helpers4ht

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper, 12pt]{article}

 \usepackage{alternative4ht}
  \altusepackage{fontspec}
  \setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
  \altusepackage{polyglossia}
  \setmainlanguage{czech}




\ifx\HCode\undefined \else
\AtBeginDocument{
\Configure{textsc}{\ifvmode\ShowPar\fi\NoFonts\HCode{<span class="sc">}}{\HCode{</span>}\EndNoFonts}
\Css{.sc{ font-variant: small-caps;}}
}\fi
\begin{document}

\section{LlAaLALALA}

small with selectfont: \rmfamily\mdseries\scshape\selectfont{Příliš žluťoučký kůň úpěl ďábelské ódy}\normalfont\\
small: \textsc{Příliš žluťoučký kůň úpěl ďábelské ódy}\\
capital: \textsc{PŘÍLIŠ ŽLUŤOUČKÝ KŮŇ ÚPĚL ĎÁBELSKÉ ÓDY}\\

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would get the same result also with default setup with `fontenc` and `inputenc`:

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper, 12pt]{article}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\ifx\HCode\undefined \else
\AtBeginDocument{
\Configure{textsc}{\ifvmode\ShowPar\fi\NoFonts\HCode{<span class="sc">}}{\HCode{</span>}\EndNoFonts}
\Css{.sc{ font-variant: small-caps;}}
}\fi
\begin{document}

\section{LlAaLALALA}

small with selectfont: \rmfamily\mdseries\scshape\selectfont{Příliš žluťoučký kůň úpěl ďábelské ódy}\normalfont\\
small: \textsc{Příliš žluťoučký kůň úpěl ďábelské ódy}\\
capital: \textsc{PŘÍLIŠ ŽLUŤOUČKÝ KŮŇ ÚPĚL ĎÁBELSKÉ ÓDY}\\

\end{document}
```

[image]

when you take a look at the HTML:

```
<span 
class="eccc1200-"><span 
class="small-caps">P</span></span><span 
class="eccc1200-">ř</span><span 
class="eccc1200-">í<span 
class="small-caps">l</span><span 
class="small-caps">i</span></span><span 
class="eccc1200-">š </span><span
```

span elements with two different classes are used for accented and unaccented letters. In the dvi file, it is recorded as following:

```
 fnt: eccc1200 at 12pt
      set: 'P'
      xxx: 't4ht@+&{35}x0159{59}'
      set: 'x'
      xxx: 't4ht@+&{35}x00ED{59}'
      set: 'xli'
      xxx: 't4ht@+&{35}x0161{59}'
      set: 'x'
      w: 4.360046pt
```

As you can see, font `eccc1200` is selected for the whole text, so `class=eccc1200-` should have been used. But small caps are obviously redefined somewhere to produce class `small-caps`, which isn't applied to accented letters. It is a bug in `tex4ht` dvi processor, which is unlikely to get fixed, as there is nobody who understand it. So as a fix, you can configure class `eccc1200-` to produce small caps through CSS:

```
\ifx\HCode\undefined \else
\AtBeginDocument{
\Configure{textsc}{\ifvmode\ShowPar\fi\NoFonts\HCode{<span class="sc">}}{\HCode{</span>}\EndNoFonts}
\Css{.sc,.eccc1200-{ font-variant: small-caps;}}
}\fi
```

Comment: it is odd: if I compile your mwe [with `inputenc`] with `make4ht -ul hello.tex` I have no problem  with the accented small caps from `\selectefont`, whether I use `\Css{.sc,.eccc1200-{ font-variant: small-caps;}}` or the original `\Css{.sc{ font-variant: small-caps;}}`. The odd thing is that, If I compile your mwe without any `css{...}`, then I have no problem with `sc` from `\selectefont`, but I loose the non-capital `sc` from `\textsc{...}`. Your trick `\Css{.sc,.eccc1200-{ font-variant: small-caps;}}` does not work when I use my mwe with ` \usepackage{alternative4ht}`.

Comment: in fact, my original mwe leads to `class="cmcsc-10x-x-120">ó<span ` and not `eccc1200-`. even if I try `\Css{.sc,.cmcsc-10x-x-120-{ font-variant: small-caps;}}` with my mwe, it does not work

Comment: @Koala you are right, different font name is used with original mwe. `\Css{.sc,.cmcsc-10x-x-120{ font-variant: small-caps;}}` works for me (note that in this case there should be no `-` at the end of class name, it should be the same as in the `class` attribute only with dot at the beginning